# php getting data from mysql database

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to get data fom a database, the problem is that I get a notice `'Array to string conversion'`, and `$array` returns 'Array'. the `get_rows` method gets all the rows using the current query. Any idea why this is happening? here's the code:

```
public function load_seat_by_number($seat_number)
    {
        $db = model_database::instance();
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM `seats` WHERE `seat_number` = '". intval($this->seat_number). "'";
        if (($array = $db->get_rows($sql)) > 0)
            return $array;
        else return FALSE;
    }
```

Comment: This `intval($this->seat_number)` should just be `intval($seat_number)`, no?

Answer (score 1):

This happens because $array is, well, an array. Use [count](http://php.net/manual/en/function.count.php) instead. Otherwise, check your database model to see if there is a way to get the number of rows from the result.

```
$array = $db->get_rows($sql);
if(count($array) > 0)
```

Comment: I tried, but it still returns 'Array'.

$array = $db->get_rows($sql);
  if(count($array) > 0)
   return $array;
  else return FALSE;

Comment: What do you expect it to return?

Comment: I want to return the data in the rows of the database. I'm sorry if I'm being noobish, but I'm really a beginner.

Comment: @icarus Then you need to echo what you need to come back, something to theh affect of `echo $get_rows['seat_number'];` --- `return $array` doesn't show the results in the array.

Comment: Your data is in the array. You'll need to iterate through the array to get the data. Use foreach (http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) to iterate through the array, though each one of those will be another array with the columns of each row.

Answer (score 0):

Use `sizeof` or `count` to get the number of elements in an array.

```
if (($array = sizeof($db->get_rows($sql))) > 0) //returns the integer value(total no. of elements in an array)
        return $array;
```

or

```
 if (($array = count($db->get_rows($sql))) > 0)  //returns the integer value(total no. of elements in an array)
            return $array;
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
public function load_seat_by_number($seat_number)
{
    $db = model_database::instance();
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM `seats` WHERE `seat_number` = '". intval($this->seat_number). "'";
    if (count($db->get_rows($sql)) > 0)
        return $db->get_rows($sql);
    else return FALSE;
}
```